# Why does Visual Studio Code show inlay hints using &* for &str type?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

[image: vscode show]

Why the use of `&*` for inlay hints?

I am trying to understand dereferencing, but why does the IDE do it like this?

Comment: @Daxelarne This is not text, this is image of how VSCode shows the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are inlay hints for "reborrows". When executing this piece of code, the compiler inserts a `&*` (called *reborrow*) there, and rust-analyzer shows that to you. It can be controlled via the setting `rust-analyzer.inlayHints.expressionAdjustmentHints.enable`.